# carla not loaded vst

Tags: wine, kde

I have two Ubuntu Studio 22.04. The first on kde, the second on xfce with ubuntu studio installed by ubuntu studio installer. On the first (KDE) Carla turns on vst, on the second it doesn't and displays different messages for example: "Failed to load file. Failed to get plugin description" "Timeout while waiting for reponse...." I tried different versions of carla, wine but still nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: What messages. They need to be in the question.

Comment: For example "Failed to load file. Failed to get plugin description"

Comment: Not in comments please use edit and add to the question.